# Bulk insert using Entity Framework for repository C# Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have following code for inserting data:

EmpService.cs

```
private readonly UnitWork _unitOfWork;  // unity framework

public MessageDetailsEntity InsertEmployee(EmployeeEntity employeeObj)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var employee = new Employee
                           {
                               name = employeeObj.Name,
                               address = employeeObj.Address,
                               is_active = true
                           };
        // call genericRepository.cs Insert method 
        _unitOfWork.EmplopyeeRepository.Insert(employee);

        _unitOfWork.Save();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

GenericRepository.cs

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal myEntities Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public GenericRepository(myEntities context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
        this.DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

I can use loop inside `TransactionScope` for multiple insert , but what is the best way to do it?

Comment: How many records are you adding typically?

Comment: around 100 for now , may be more later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to design unit of work to support bulk operations and give more performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304855/how-to-design-unit-of-work-to-support-bulk-operations-and-give-more-performance)