# bulk insert into database in repository pattern and unit of work with best performance

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

i want to insert 800k row in my repository and then commit. i send every 15k record to repository and commit it but its too slow.

```
        foreach (var imei in command.IMEIItems) {

            var newIMEI = new IMEI(imei.IMEINumber, command.PromotionId);
            _imeiRepository.Add(newIMEI);
        }

        _unitOfWork.Commit();
```

my problem is about foreach loop. its too slow to add in repository.
commit is fast.

my repository:

```
         public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity != null)
        {
            TEntity addedTEntity = ObjectSet.Add(entity); // add new item in this set
            return addedTEntity;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

    }

     protected virtual IDbSet<TEntity> ObjectSet
    {
        get
        {
            return _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>();
        }
    }

     public virtual IDbSet<TEntity> CreateSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : 
      class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @amirhossein do you need to wait for this to complete before moving to the next step? if not then look at something like Hangfire to run this in the background.  Here is another link that also might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304855/how-to-design-unit-of-work-to-support-bulk-operations-and-give-more-performance. And another about thread-safety of EF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455634/entity-framework-thread-safety

Comment: @TsTeaTime yes. i use WCF at this project. i send every 15k row to this wcf service. and if i do it async, i think its may be bad.

Comment: Sigh - and what is _unitOfWork.CreateSet doing? We did not see that code either

Comment: @SirRufo i added CreateSet method to my question. this project was developed 3 years ago. i did not know who use this pattern. i work on this project now and want solve performance problem. i think problem is ObjectSet and CreateSet not supported parallel. could you help me?

Comment: **Bulk** operations are **not** a good match for Entity Framework - and adding another level of complexity with a repository pattern makes it even worse. If you **really** want to bulk-import - then use low-level ADO.NET code directly (see the documentation on the `SqlBulkCopy` class).

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, assuming that your Repo method is thread safe -

Can you try using `Parallel.for`considering your large data size. Something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop)

However, if your data size is relatively small, then a `Parallel.For` might be less efficient, taking into account the CPU context switch overhead.

So, might be worth checking the size of the input collection and then deciding between a normal for and a parallel for,

Comment: thnaks for you answer. i think ObjectSet and CreateSet method does not support parallel. i think i have to change My Add Method.what is your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

**Add vs AddRange**

That's a very common error to use the Add method to add multiple entities. In fact, it's the DetectChanges method that's **INSANELY** slow.

- The Add method DetectChanges after every record added.
- The AddRange method DetectChanges after all records are added.

See: [Entity Framework - Performance Add](http://entityframework.net/improve-ef-add-performance)

---

To solve your issue,

The idea is probably to add a new method `AddRange` in your repository. However, you will face another issue because the `IDbSet` doesn't have the `AddRange` method but the `DbSet` does. So maybe you will need to make a cast.

---

**EDIT:** answer comment

> how cast i'll need to make?

It depend on what is, in reality, your `IDbSet<TEntity>`. I mean, that's not an instance of an interface, it must inherit from a class.

It probably an instance of `DbSet<TEntity>` so if that's the case, you only have to cast it

```
((DbSet<TEntity>)ObjectSet).AddRange(items);
```

Comment: thanks. i have added AddRange Method in my repository and As you said, this happened. how cast i'll need to make?